# IBOutlet is not released

Tags: uiview, release, retain, iboutlet

I have this problem. I have two IBOutlets and as properties and I am retaining them.

```
@interface MCNavigationController : UIViewController 

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MCNavBar *navBar;

@end
```

The problem is that in dealloc, after I do all the releases, contentView and navBar are still not deallocated.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [contentView release];
    NSLog(@"%@",contentView.superview);
    [navBar release];
    NSLog(@"%@",navBar.superview);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view);

    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"%@",navBar.superview);
    NSLog(@"%@",contentView.superview);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view);
```

}

And in the log this is what I get:

```
2012-08-21 14:48:05.646 ShopRite[4250:12503] <UIView: 0x66b77d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x66b7800>>
2012-08-21 14:48:05.649 ShopRite[4250:12503] <UIView: 0x66b77d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x66b7800>>
2012-08-21 14:48:05.650 ShopRite[4250:12503] <UIView: 0x66b77d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x66b7800>>
2012-08-21 14:48:05.650 ShopRite[4250:12503] <UIView: 0x66b77d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x66b7800>>
2012-08-21 14:48:05.651 ShopRite[4250:12503] <UIView: 0x66b77d0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x66b7800>>
2012-08-21 14:48:13.726 ShopRite[4250:12503] *** -[MCNavigationController view]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x66b5f20
```

but I should get a "message sent to deallocated instance for navBar and contentView, like I et for self.view. I am quite sure that I don't retain them anywhere else or add them to some other view.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> after I do all the releases, contentView and navBar are still not
>   deallocated.

Those views could be retained in many ways:

1. These views are presumably subviews of the controller's view (therefore retained by the controller's view). And the controller's view will only be released in `UIViewController`'s `dealloc`, which happens at the *end* of your `dealloc`, so it hasn't happened at the place you logged it.
2. Since you are loading a view controller with a xib, the view controller retains the xib and all of its objects while it is loaded. So again, this will be released in `UIViewController`'s `dealloc`, which happens at the *end* of your `dealloc`.
3. They could be still retained by the autorelease pool if someone retained and then autoreleased it. (Lots of code retains and then autoreleases objects, since it is never wrong to do so.) Therefore, exactly when an object is deallocated is not always predictable. Just worry about doing memory management correctly on your end, and don't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are using this with xib.

If you are using xib then this will be released when it will be removed from superview or remove from window.

When we use IBOutlet then we do not need to do release.

Comment: I am using a nib and the ViewController dealloc method is called so its view is removed from the superview but still, those two outlets are not released properly. If the property is created using retain then we need to release it in dealloc.